# Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function (with correct number of parameter)

Tags: web3js

I've the following contract function:

```
/*Solidity Code, inside my contract*/
function isGranted(address _user, address _content) view external returns (bool) {
    return (grantedAccess[_user][_content]);
}
```

That works on Remix IDE without any problem.

Then I wrote a Web3JS frontend

```
this.catalog = (this.web3.eth.contract(this.props.catalog.abi)).at(this.props.catalog.address);
this.catalog.isGranted(
            this.web3.eth.defaultAccount, //Parameter1
            this.state.address, //Parameter2
        (err, res) => { //Callback
            if(!err){
                console.log(res);
                this.setState(this.setState({userHasRightAccess: res}));
            } else {
                console.error(err);
            }
        })
```

But the execution returns `Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function`. I tried to add the other optional parameter to Web3js function but the error remains. Any idea/solution?

(I don't use Truffle or any more framework. Web3JS version is "0.19.0")

Edit: I've update the library to 0.20.6 version

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that an argument was `undefined`. I'll added a check and now works

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking that both parameters:

`this.web3.eth.defaultAccount, //Parameter1
this.state.address, //Parameter2`

actually have values at the point that you pass them into `this.catalog.isGranted`.

You can do this by just calling `console.log` with them just before you enter the web3 function - I've seen this issue when one of the parameters is `undefined`.